# Multi step form category specified fields in vue js

Tags: python, html, css, django, vue.js

I have built multi step form by using vue js. When user type is **"business"** we have to prompt multi step form in that we have 3 steps They are.

**first step form:-**
This form contains only one fields **Category field**. If user enters first form field then user can able to open category specified fields.

**second step form:-**
This form contains **category specified fields**. If user entered for example IT in first form in second form it has salary, job type,..etc.

**third step form:-**
Price package form for business user.

If logged in user type is **"Consumer"** we need prompt like this multi step form. we have 3 steps again her, Those are.

**First step form:-** In this we have **category field**. If user enters category then user clclick on next button we prompt next form.
**Second step form:-** In this second form it prompts **We asks a question like weather he want to continue as consumer or business in this form we have two radio button if user selects consumer we need prompt category specified fields again in third form. else if user selects business we need to prompt signuup form to update user to business in thrid form.**

Here, I am not understanding how to reuse category specified fields from **second step to third step**.

Please, If any one help me to achieve this, Thank you.

** code snippet **

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

```
      <div id="app">
               <form action="">
                  <fieldset class="postad_fieldset" v-if="step == 1">
                      <a href="/home" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top: 7px;margin-right: 5px;" type="button">×</a>
                      <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;">
                          <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                              <p><input class="vue_input" style="width: 93%;" type="text" v-model="category" placeholder="Search your category"
                                        name="category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type"></p>

                                
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </div>
                  </fieldset>


                  <fieldset class="postad_fieldset" v-if="step == 2">
                      <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;">
<!--if we enter category 'Real Estate | Single Family Homes' in first screen at category field. If that entered category and this template
is matched then based on that category we are prompting this template -->
                    {% if user_type == 'business' %}
                       <template v-if="category == 'Real Estate | Single Family Homes'">

                           <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                       <p class="select_p">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bedrooms" name="bedrooms_p" v-model="bedrooms" id="id_post_bedrooms">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bathrooms" name="bathrooms_p" v-model="bathrooms" id="id_post_bathrooms">
                       </p>

                       <p class="select_p">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="SQFT" name="Square_ft_p" v-model="Square_ft" maxlength="100" id="id_post_Square_ft">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Lot size" name="lot_size_p" v-model="lot_size" maxlength="50" id="id_post_lot_size">
                       </p>

                     

                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </template>

<!--                      -->
                      <template v-else-if="category == 'laptop'">
                          <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                       <h2> laptop template</h2>

                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </template>

                      <template v-else-if="category == 'computer'">
                          <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                       <h2> computer template</h2>

                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </template>

                      <template v-else-if="category == 'IT'">
                          <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                          <p class="select_p">
                              <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title_it" v-model="title_it" maxlength="200" id="id_post_title_it">
                              <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Experience" name="experience_it" v-model="experience" maxlength="200" id="id_post_experience_it">
                          </p>

                          <p class="select_p">
                              <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location_it" v-model="location" maxlength="200" id="id_post_location_it">
                              <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Salary" name="salary_it" v-model="salary" maxlength="200" id="id_post_salary_it">
                          </p>


                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </template>

                     
                          {% else %}
                          <template v-if="">

                              <h1 class="post_adttl">Consumer</h1>
                              <input class="consumer_radio" type="radio" id="consumer" name="flag" value="Personal Ad"
                                     v-model="picked">
                              <label style="position: relative;left: 1px;"class="personal_postad">Personal Ad:</label>
                              <p class="postad_p">Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear <br>
                                  with "sale by owner
                                  tag"</p><br>
                              <input style="position: relative;
    width: 4%;
    top: -37px;"class="business_radio" type="radio" id="business" name="flag" value="business"
                                     v-model="picked">
                              <label style="position: relative;top: -49px;" class="Business_postad">Business Ad:</label>
                              <p style="position: relative;left: 0px;top: -47px;" class="postad_p">Do you want to
                                  upgrade to business account to post more <br>ads per month</p>

                              <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;"
                                      @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous
                              </button>
                              <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()"
                                      class="btn btn-primary">Next
                              </button>
                          </template>

                          {% endif %}
                  </div>
                  </fieldset>



                  <fieldset class="postad_fieldset" v-if="step == 3">

                      <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;">
                        {% if user_type == 'business' %}
                          <template v-if="">
                              <h1 class="post_adttl">Package</h1>
                            <p>
                                <input style="width: 4%;" type="radio" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1" value="$4.99 - 12 Ads - Month"><span
                                class="radio_price1"> $2.99 - 6 Ads - Month</span>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <input style="width: 4%;" class="price2" type="radio" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1" value="$4.99 - 12 Ads - Month"><span
                                class="radio_price2" style="position: relative;
                                top: -13px;"> $4.99 - 12 Ads - Month</span>
                            </p>


                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                          </template>
                          {% endif %}
                                <!-- if user picked Personal Ad from 1st step. -->
                                <!-- But here already this template is avialabble in first step how to display that template here. -->
                          <template v-if="picked == 'Personal Ad'">

                           <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                           <p class="select_p">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bedrooms" name="bedrooms_p" v-model="bedrooms" id="id_post_bedrooms">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bathrooms" name="bathrooms_p" v-model="bathrooms" id="id_post_bathrooms">
                           </p>

                           <p class="select_p">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="SQFT" name="Square_ft_p" v-model="Square_ft" maxlength="100" id="id_post_Square_ft">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Lot size" name="lot_size_p" v-model="lot_size" maxlength="50" id="id_post_lot_size">
                           </p>

                           <p class="select_p">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Total rooms" v-model="total_rooms" name="total_rooms_p" id="id_post_total_rooms">
                                <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Stories" name="stories_p" v-model="stories" maxlength="200" id="id_post_stories">
                           </p>

                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                      </template>
                      <!-- end if user picked Personal Ad from 1st step. -->

                      <!-- if user picked business from 2nd step. -->
                          <template v-if="picked == 'business'">
                                  <h1 style="font-size:25px;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:10px;">Sign Up</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:12px;float:left;color:grey;">Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
                    <div class="form-group new-signup">
                        <input id="email_business" name="email" placeholder="Business Email Address"
                               style="border:1px solid #01ABAA;"
                               type="email">
                        <span class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa1"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id='password_consumer' class="InputPassword password_r"
                               name="password_consumer" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="validate_password()"><br>
                        <p id="password_result12_invalid" class="error_verify"
                           style="font-size: 8px;position: relative;top: 9px;"></p>
                        <span class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa1"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                    <button class="login-btn" id="submit_consumer" disabled>
                        Sign Up
                    </button>

                          </template>
                      </div>
                  </fieldset>

                  
               </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: what is category specified field? is it `picked`?

Comment: Actually I have given picked on business ad. If business ad radiobutton is selected then we are prompting signup form. and my issue while we selecting personal ad the we need to prompt category specified means whatever category we enter based on that template we need to prompt if we checked personal radio button also